# When did Harley Quinn first join the suicide squad?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, suicide-squad, suicide-squad-2016

I know Margot Robbie is set to play Harley Quinn in the upcoming *Suicide Squad* movie,  and that the character was originally introduced in one of the many *Batman* cartoons.

What I'm wondering is when did Harley Quinn first appear in a *Suicide Squad* comic?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there anything else you need in an answer?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots no this one just slipped through the cracks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Suicide Squad Vol 4 #1 (New 52):

> After a falling out with the Joker, she goes into a murderous frenzy,
>   directed towards people responsible for the Joker's imprisonment.
>   Captured by Black Canary, she is forcibly inducted into the Suicide
>   Squad by Amanda Waller. However, when she discovers that the Joker
>   is rumored to be dead, it takes a further toll in her already addled
>   mind, and betraying the Suicide Squad, she puts their safety and
>   secrecy at risk by turning herself into the Gotham Police Department
>   in a plot to gain access to the skinned face of the Joker.(Vol 4#6)............

(Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harley_Quinn#The_New_52), dc.wikia.com/ ([1](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Suicide_Squad_Vol_4_1),[2](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Harleen_Quinzel_(Prime_Earth)#Kicked_in_the_Teeth))